# How can I format string of time in dart flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, time, hour

Ex my string of time is 05.30(+6) from json api ...I want to convert it actual time format so that i can subtract the time from actual device time.

Answer (score 0):

For complete timestamps you can use the [parse](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/parse.html) method of `DateTime`.

If you really have the time only, then that's the domain of the `TimeOfDay` class, but as soon as timezones are a thing, time-only does not make sense really. You might end up in another *day* in a different timezone.